# Every field with characterisitic $p$ contains the field $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

I seem to hold a very loose grasp of the concept of fields - I've encountered this question:
Show that every finite field with characteristic $p$ contains $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (i.e. $\mathbb{Z}_p = \{0,...,p-1\}$).
Now my question is what exactly is a field of characteristic $p$?

My second question: Show that every field of characteristic $0$ contains $\mathbb{Q}$ as a subfield?

Regards.

Comment: Write $1$ for the multiplicative identity of the field $F$. Look at $1,1+1,1+1+1,1+1+1+1,\cdots$.  If none of these is $0$, we say $F$ has characteristic $0$. If one of these is $0$, let $k$ be the smallest integer such that $1+\cdots +1=0$. It turns out that $k$ is prime. This $k$ is called the characteristic of $F$.

Comment: So doesnt this mean that every field of charectaristic p is actoualy Zp ? or isomorphic to Zp? but i cant seem to understand why it would contain Zp.

Comment: @Nimrodshn No, not every element of a field needs to be represented as $1+1+1+\dots +1$. For example, in $\mathbb Q$, you can't represent $1/2$ that way.

Comment: The field $F=\{0,1,a,a+1\}$ with addition modulo 2 (ie. for example $a+(a+1) = (a+a)+1=1$) and multipliction goven by $a^2=a+1$ (hence e.g. $(a+1)^2=a^2+2a+1=3a+2=a$) is a field with four elements. It properly  contains $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$

Comment: It contains a field isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$. It can be much bigger, even infinite.

Answer (score 2):

If $F$ is a field use the ring morphism $h:\Bbb Z\to F$ defined by $n\mapsto n.1_F$ and regarded it' kernel. It's kernel is a subgroup of $(\Bbb Z,+)$ so it is of the form $\ker h=p\Bbb Z$. Now discuss the cases $p=0$ and $p\neq 0$.

Comment: If $p=0$ then $F$ you can show that $F$ contain $\Bbb Q$. If $p\neq 0$ by the universal propriety of the quotient $h$ induce an injective  morphism fro  $\Bbb Z/(\ker h)=\Bbb Z/(p\Bbb Z)=\Bbb Z_p$ to $F$